# Customising Sharepoint 2010 Search Results based on URLs in fields

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I have what seems to me a complex problem.

I have a list, that has two text fields in it. Paths are stored in the fields, in the following forms:

- For a url: "URL,http://www.google.com"
- For a document: "Document,/Lists/Test/Test.txt"

The listitem could have these values filled or might not.

In the case that one value is filled, I need to **add** a result to the search results to link to the url / document in the field

In the case that two values are filled, I need to **add** two results to search, both linking to their respective field values (either a document or a hyperlink)

I know this is done using xslt in the search results, but that is a dark art to me, and my google-fu is not returning helpful results.

Any help / pointers will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The challenge in 2010 is that you have to create a conditional expression, for example on Content Type, to first detect that you have the right result. (In 2013 this is WAY easier.) Then in your true condition evaluate the field values and render the results the way you prefer.

If you are totally new to the process have a look here for pointers on getting started in 2010: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/09/30/take-control-of-search-xsl/